# API calls inside mapreduce job

Tags: java, api, hadoop, mapreduce, elastic-map-reduce

I would want to ask you about the inconveniences of calling an external API while running a map reduce job. which are the drawbacks?

Some examples: If inside the mapper we need to geocode an address and we call a google maps api, or  calling an external DB in order to get related elements of an item, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perfectly OK to make a call to an external API as long as there are no DB calls in the external API. In many ways this is preferred to writing your logic over again. Often times you want your MapReduce jobs to be nothing more than wrapper's around logic written in a non MapReduce context. This make's for better testable code.

However, making external DB calls is STRONGLY discouraged. This will drastically reduce the speed of your MapReduce jobs as every call would be a random access call. In addition, having several thousand Map/Reduce taks hitting your DB at the same time could bring the DB to it's knees. If you need related elements, it's preferable to have all the elements on HDFS and doing a join in MapReduce. If the DB you're talking about is a NoSQL store such as Cassandra or HBase, they'll have a batch export feature to export the entire table onto HDFS.

Comment: But what if you need to look for the related items for , let's say, 2 million items and the number of posible options is 30 million is there any kind of map reduce pattern for that?

Comment: Is that 30 million possible for each of the 2 million items or a 30 million total? If it's 30 million total, then your best option is to put the 30 million items on HDFS and doing a join in MapReduce

Comment: 30 million possible for each of the 2 million items, the task to acomplish is to match the elements.

Comment: How many total items do you expect to have? It still seems like the best idea would be to do a join in MR

Comment: There are 30 million possible for each of the 2 million items, that will make a 60 million input. Thanks for your insights